# What is the opposite of ETL?

Tags: reporting, etl, data-warehouse

ETL (extract, transform, load) is the process of getting data into a data warehouse from various sources.
Is there a name for the opposite process? Extracting data from a data warehouse, transforming it and putting it into a table - usually to feed a reporting tool.

Answer (score 2):

Technically speaking, the opposite is of an ETL is an ELT.

Instead of extract, transform, then load, an ELT is an extract, load, then transform. The choice between which of the two pipelines should be used depends on the system and the nature of the data. For example, the process of bringing data into a relational database necessarily requires a transformation before loading, but other frameworks, such as Hadoop, are better able to handle unstructured data and apply structure to it after loading takes place.

Answer (score 2):

Since this question has been asked, 6 years ago (!) a lot has changed in the ETL landscape.

There is a new trend called "Reverse ETL" which is the idea of taking cleaned/ transformed/modeled data from your warehouse **back into** the SaaS applications (Salesforce, Marketo, Zendesk, HubSpot, etc) that your teams use.

The main tools are

- [getCensus](https://www.getcensus.com/)
- [Seekwell](https://www.seekwell.io/)
- [Grouparoo](https://www.grouparoo.com/)

You can read more about this nascent trend [here](https://blog.getcensus.com/what-is-reverse-etl/) and [here](https://medium.com/memory-leak/reverse-etl-a-primer-4e6694dcc7fb) too

Answer (score 0):

The ETL abbreviation applies to any extract, transform and load sequence. It can be applied to extracting data from a data warehouse, transforming the data and loading the transformed data into a table.

In your question you have two ETL sequences; one that loads the data into the data warehouse and one that extracts information from the data warehouse and loads this data into the table.